# Proving that solutions to linear systems form a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been given to systems of equations and I have to prove whether their solutions are or aren't vector spaces, but I'm confused on how to do it.
The first system:
$$
x+y+z=0\\
x+y+2z=1
$$
The second system is:
$$x+y+z=0\\
x+y+2z=0$$

I think that for the second system once you find the solution, you're solving for $Ax=b$, but if I have two solutions $x1$ and $x2 A(x1+x2)$ doesn't equal $b$ so it shouldn't be a vector space. For the, first system since it's homogenous I believe it is a vector space.

Comment: Start by saying what is the definition of a vector space.

Comment: I think that for it to be a vector space the objects in the set, have to be able to be added together and scaled.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment, in order to have a vector space one needs to be able to add two vectors and get a vector in the same set, or scale a vector to yield a vector in the same set. In the first system subtract the first equation from the second, to get $z=1$. Then the first equation becomes $$x+y+1=0$$or $$y=-x-1$$
So the solution in a vector form is $$\vec v=(x,-x-1,1)$$
If you scale this vector, say by a factor of $2$, you need to be able to write it in the same form:
$$2\vec v=(2x,-2x-2,2)$$
Notice that the last term of $2\vec v$ is $2$, and $2\ne 1$. So $2\vec v$ is not a solution of the first system. So the solutions of the first system do not form a vector space.

Can you do that for the second system?

Comment: Thanks. I think that for the second one you can do that. After subtracting the first equation from the second you get z=0. Plugging that in to the first equation gives: x+y+0=0. So, x=-y and the vector form would be: v=(-y ,y ,0) and when you scale this by 2 you get (-2y, y, 0) which would work. And when you add them, this should still give a vector within the set.

Comment: Correct. Note that in your comment it should be $(-2y,2y,0)$. Which you can write using $2y=y_1$ as $(-y_1,y_1,0)$